# How I can get value from label data-type="radio"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How can I get value from `label data-type="radio"`? This the code I'm using:

```
<label id="condition" class="btn btn-default toggle-class" data-toggle="active" data-type="radio" style="width:120px; !important">
    New
</label>
<label id="condition" class="btn btn-default toggle-class active" data-toggle="active" data-type="radio" style="width:120px; !important">
    Used
</label>
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Have you got an code example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Can you describe (a) what action would start this — *e.g.* "the second label is clicked" — and (b) what result you'd expect — *e.g.* "Used" or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can get it with jQuery `data()`

```
<label data-type="radio" id="myLabel">My Radio label</label>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
      console.log($('#myLabel').data('type')); //Logs radio
  });
</script>
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/s31u5xu0/